# Python/SodaPY API returns unhashable type: dict

Tags: python, dictionary, enumeration, soda

I have used a SodaPY client to download JSON data from the City of New York Open Gov initiative.   SodaPY provides code and the following comments for using their client:

```
# First 2000 results, returned as JSON from API / converted to Python list of
# dictionaries by sodapy.
results = client.get("qiz3-axqb", limit=2000)
# Convert to pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
```

When I inspect the dataframe using method describe(), I receive an error message for feature 'location':

```
...
pandas/_libs/hashtable_func_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.value_count_object()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I am trying to parse this data type to a pair of GIS coordinates.   Here is the first element of the column:

```
{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-73.917305, 40.723854]}
```

I have tried using 'enumerate' to unpack this, but it doesn't seem to unpack as I expected (I am looking to extract the pair of coordinates at the end of each dict element):

```
In:
for (i, v) in enumerate(df['location'][:4]):
    print (i,v)
Out:
(0, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-73.917305, 40.723854]})
(1, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-73.871315, 40.83228]})
(2, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-73.93294, 40.70393]})
(3, {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-73.92817, 40.714207]})
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on and suggest a pythonic technique for extracting this information?  TY!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this one out.   I referenced key 'coordinates.'   Not sure why the other key/value pair is present, as all data is 'points.'  Maybe one for the SodaPY crew.